# Better random number generator for Integers

Tags: java, random

Currently, I'm using random numbers to generate positions of components in a JPanel. I found that using `Random.nextInt(6000);` returned too many numbers that were less than 100, by too many, I mean the greater majority of them were less than 100. So I looked into it, and found a higher quality Random Number Generator that uses `Long` so I took the liberty to format it properly (See implementation below). After that I'm getting too many numbers in the 1000-2000 range.

After testing with a counter variable, when I generate 2000 numbers around 1350 of them are inside of that range.

**I need a number generator that is more random, or even one that is** ***truly random*** (which I don't expect to get, but would be nice if I could get).

Random Class:

```
public class HighQualityRandom extends Random {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
  private long u;
  private long v = 4101842887655102017L;
  private long w = 1;

  public HighQualityRandom() {
    this(System.nanoTime());
  }
  public HighQualityRandom(long seed) {
    l.lock();
    u = seed ^ v;
    nextLong();
    v = u;
    nextLong();
    w = v;
    nextLong();
    l.unlock();
  }

  public long nextLong() {
    l.lock();
    try {
      u = u * 2862933555777941757L + 7046029254386353087L;
      v ^= v >>> 17;
      v ^= v << 31;
      v ^= v >>> 8;
      w = 4294957665L * (w & 0xffffffff) + (w >>> 32);
      long x = u ^ (u << 21);
      x ^= x >>> 35;
      x ^= x << 4;
      long ret = (x + v) ^ w;
      return ret;
    } finally {
      l.unlock();
    }
  }

  public int next(int bits) {
    return (int) (nextLong() >>> (64-bits));
  }

}
```

Implementation:

```
    public int getRandomX(){
    HighQualityRandom ran = new HighQualityRandom();
    int rand = (int) ran.nextLong();
    String p = rand + "";
    if(rand < 0){
        rand = rand * -1;
    }
    p = rand + "";
    p = p.substring(0, 4);
    rand = Integer.parseInt(p);
    while(rand > 6144){
        rand = (int) ran.nextLong();
        p = rand + "";
        if(rand < 0){
            rand = rand * -1;
        }
        p = rand + "";
        p = p.substring(0,4);
        rand = Integer.parseInt(p);
    }
    System.out.print("X is: " + rand + " Y is: ");
    return rand;
}
public int getRandomY(){
    HighQualityRandom ran = new HighQualityRandom();
    int rand = (int) ran.nextLong();
    String p = rand + "";
    if(rand < 0){
        rand = rand * -1;
    }
    p = rand + "";
    p = p.substring(0, 4);
    rand = Integer.parseInt(p);
    while(rand > 4608){
        rand = (int) ran.nextLong();
        p = rand + "";
        if(rand < 0){
            rand = rand * -1;
        }
        p = rand + "";
        p = p.substring(0,4);

        rand = Integer.parseInt(p);
    }
    System.out.println(rand);
    return rand;
}
```

As an explanation for what I'm doing to the `long` to get my 4 digit number:

1. If it's negative, multiply by negative 1.
2. Make it a String.
3. Substring the first 4 digits
4. If it's too big: do it again.

As a side note, what is the `seed` parameter supposed to be in the `Random` class? I tried googling it and people were talking about encryption stuff...

EDIT:

Implementation using java.util.random():

```
    public int getRandomX(){
    Random ran = new Random();
    int rand = ran.nextInt(6144);

    if(rand <= 100){
        Game.between++;
    }

    return rand;
}
public int getRandomY(){
    Random ran = new Random();
    int rand = ran.nextInt(4608);

    if(rand <= 100){
        Game.between++;
    }
    System.out.println(Game.between);

    return rand;
}
```

On average, about 37-40 of them were less than 100 (Out of 1000). So I was wrong, definitely not 50% of them are on or outside said box. BUT: Out of `28311552` possible solutions (Map is 6144x4608) to choose from, it seems like that's too many to be stuck at <100.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem with `Random.nextInt` to start with.

Comment: I strongly doubt that the problem is with the library random number generators. `Random` may not be cryptographically strong, but it sure isn't biased in the way you are observing. If you're getting too many numbers less than 100 (or in the 1000-2000 range), then the problem is almost certainly in how you are using the package. Please show us that code instead of the guts of a substitute PRNG that doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: http://archive.wired.com/wired/archive/11.08/random.html

Comment: @ControlAltDel, That's why I said I didn't expect a truly random number generator. The last sentence of what you linked.

Comment: yeah, we don't believe you! lol. also, try ThreadLocalRandom instead, which should be faster.

Comment: @bayou.io What's the difference? Speed? I'm not too worried about load speed...

Comment: no big deal either way; it's just a matter of principle. `Random`, like other ancient classes (e.g. `Vector`), was designed with too much synchronization cost.

Comment: also, you wouldn't have run into this bug if you used ThreadLocalRandom:)

Comment: @NicholasEason The seed value is in the API for `java.util.Random`.  It's just any `long`. I'm not sure why you care where the value comes from, but it's a fixed value bitwise-and'ed with System.nanoTime()  (Java 8).  The API gives very detailed information about how values are generated.

Comment: @MadConan I was just curious and couldn't find out what it was by googling it, so I brought it up here.

Comment: Your digit-stripping thing is causing your problem. The XOR-shift generator works fine, but its range is 32 bits--a power of two, not a power of 10, so there's no reason to think that decimal digits of its output will be random. So take the random value and use mod(10000) rather than picking out decimal digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing, but here is a small example program:

```
Random r = new Random();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000_000; i++)
    if (r.nextInt(6000) < 100)
        count++;
System.out.println(count);
```

Calls `Random.nextInt(6000)` a million times. And the result is:

```
16655
```

In ideal case it would be: `100/5999 * 1000000 = 16669`. I think that's pretty close.

You are doing something wrong. Please post you original code proving that `Random.nextInt(6000)` gives less than 100 in more than 50 % of the cases.

For purposes of generating random numbers in a game, [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) is perfectly fine. There is also [`java.security.SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) but you don't need that for a game, and also it is significantly slower.

**EDIT:**

To your edit: you are always creating a new `Random` instance! Don't do that. If you always create a new `Random` instance and you don't specify a seed value, it will be seeded based on the current time of your computer. This will in itself reduce the "randomness" of the generator.

Do as in my example: create a `Random` instance, optionally seed it to wherever you want to, and always use that!

**Edit #2:**

The seed: it is something like the "state" of the random number generator. Quoting from the `Random` class javadoc:

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

In practice you only need to set the seed if you want to reproduce the same sequence. For example you save a game / replay, and you want to re-paly the  game. In this case you would save the starting seed along with the game/replay, and when playing the game again, you would set the saved seed and thus you would get the same random sequence.

Comment: @NicholasEason And you also check the edit that I made.

Comment: I asked in my question, but everyone seems to be ignoring it.. what ***is*** the seed?

Comment: Randomizing the seed seems to have decreased the count to about 32-35. Is this good practice?

Comment: @NicholasEason In practice you only need to set the seed if you want to reproduce the same sequence. See the edit for example. To have your count close to ideal, only thing that is needed to have one `Random` instance and do not create it each time when a random number is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your digit-stripping thing is causing your problem. The XOR-shift generator works fine, but its range is 64 bits--a power of two, not a power of 10, so there's no reason to think that decimal digits of its output will be random. So take the random value and use mod(10000) rather than picking out decimal digits.

99% of programmers don't understand the math well enough to improve on an RNG or a Crypto cipher. Unfortunately, about 10% of programmers think they're in that 1% who can. The moral: don't mess with an RNG, just use it as intended and read the docs carefully.

Comment: Nitpick: The suggestion to use modulo will not make for a perfectly even distribution either, if the modulo happens not to be a power of two. Smaller numbers will still have a higher frequency, thats immediately obvious if you imagine a RNG providing only 14 bits of randomness (0-16383) and take the modulo from there. Numbers in range 0-6383 have then *twice* the chance of appearing than numbers 6384-9999. Modulo is not a general solution to the biasing problem, which makes your following rant somewhat ironic.

Comment: Well, my goal wasn't to "improve" the RNG, it was to format it to a 4 digit Integer.

Comment: Yes, and the common way to do that is with mod. It's not perfect as pointed out, but at 64 bits it's good enough. If you really need perfect you have to do rejection sampling.